# How to display None in a table if the table is empty rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a table of names. I want to display none in the table if the table is empty. I am using haml, BS4, and rails 4. So far I have tried this:

```
 - if
   %table.table.table-hover
     - @bill.cosponsors == blank? do
        %tr
           %td= "None"
- else
    %table.table.table-hover
       - @bill.cosponsors.each do |cosponsor|
          %tr
             %td= cosponsor.cosponsor
```

Comment: Don't use `%td= "None"`, use `%td None`.

Comment: Already tried that with no success

Comment: Well, it's the right way to use Haml, so you should go back to trying it. What you're doing now is wrong. You should not be using `= "..."` to output a static string.

Comment: Your partial answer did the trick so Im going to go with that. Thanks. I am going to read up rendering partials as I am new to all this.

Comment: The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) contain a wealth of useful information on rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `render @collection` to render the correct partial for each item in the collection, instead of manually iterating over the collection.

This will return `nil` if the collection is empty, allowing you to conditionally render a different empty partial in that case.

If your model is named 'Cosponsor', you should do this:

- app/views/cosponsors/index.html.haml

  ```
  %table
    = render(@bill.cosponsors) || render('empty_table')
  ```
- app/views/cosponsors/_cosponsor.html.haml

  ```
  %tr
    %td= cosponsor.cosponsor
  ```
- app/views/cosponsors/_empty_table_partial.html.haml

  ```
  %tr.empty
    %td There are no cosponsors
  ```

See [Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 1):

I use `.any?` method. If @bill.consponsors.any? then display them else, display "none"

Answer (score 0):

`blank?` should be checked on the attribute itself. You could move out from the if the table tag to DRY your code a little bit:

```
%table.table.table-hover
   - if @bill.cosponsors.blank?
        %tr
           %td "None"
   - else
     - @bill.cosponsors.each do |cosponsor|
         %tr
           %td= cosponsor.cosponsor
```

Comment: When I use the if else I get an error saying "syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end ". I have double checked my space and indentation and that does not seem to be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a HAML expert, but I copy/pasted your code and I think you need to remove `do` keyword in the if statement. Try that